# Half day in Dublin for oldies

Tags: recommendations, dublin

I'll have six hours break in Dublin, when I'll be travelling with my old parents (70+). What should I show them, so the trip wouldn't be too tiring for them? Price is less relevant than comfort.

Should I take short / comfortable passage (what?) to the city center and show them something around? Or would it be better to get shortest passage to nearest DART station (which one, how to get there?) and bring them around countryside, like for example to visit beautiful Howth?

Can I buy one-day ticket for DART / local transport at the airport and how much will I pay for that?

Comment: How are you getting into Dublin? 6 hours from the ferry terminal is very different to 6 hours from the airport with 30 minutes each way to the city + checkin times on departure

Comment: Taking tea at any one of the spots along the Liffey might be wonderful...  Watching the world go by can be momentous depending upon the company.

Comment: I would consider a 'tour' including some famous sights. As time is short, you might want to consider a taxi. But do check that the traffic is not too bad that time of day.

Comment: @Gagravarr Sorry, for not making this clear, but I thought, this is quite obvious. I'll have around 6 hours of free time, excluding travel. My flights lands and 10:00 and another one takes-off at 18:00. So, excluding checkouts / checkings etc. I should have around six hours free time from airport door till airport door.

Comment: Your question is about to be closed because we have no idea what your parents are into. We are not here to organise your trip (not a travel agency) but we can help directing you to the right places or resources. So to make this question possible to answer, you should say what your parents would expect: visit a museum (art, science, ..), have a bus tour, having tea, tasting beer, ... The possibilities are endless and two 70+ people are not likely to want to do the same.

Comment: @Vince I must admit, that I'm very surprised, that this question is about to be closed. When someone would ask me about any city, that I know quite good, giving me only amount of time for sightseeing and average age of visitors, I'd have absolutely no problems in naming all interesting (IMHO) places, in all these cities, according to given parameters. I don't understand, what my parent's interest has to do with this and how this question is not answerable. I thought, this site is for throwing some trip ideas, among which OP selects the one, that suits him or her the best.

Comment: I agree, it is possible, that is called a guidebook. There are [websites for travel guidebooks](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Dublin) and websites for travel questions and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to see some of the city's highlights, but don't want to walk too much, then I'd say your best bet is a hop-on, hop-off bus tour. This will let you see much of the city, learn about it (there's a guide on board giving commentary), and will let you get between the tourist destinations you might want to visit.

I've heard good things about the [Hop on, Hop off bus run by Dublin Buses](http://www.dublinsightseeing.ie/citytour.aspx), who have two routes covering the main sights, with one ticket between them. They also run the quicker of the two [buses from the airport to the city](http://www.dublinsightseeing.ie/airlink/index.aspx), and have friendly staff at the airport who can sell you a combined ticket for the airport bus and the hop-on hop-off bus. At the airport, you want the green double-decker Airlink bus, not the Blue airport express bus. The airport bus driver can advise you where to get off in the city centre to change to the tour bus. Journey time is about 30 minutes from the airport to the city, and there's 3-4 buses an hour, so you should have a decent amount of time in the city centre.

Depending on weather and jetlag and energy levels, you can select where to get off at, then carry on round to the next place of interest. Trinity College is well worth a visit, which the bus goes to, and I'd say the [National Museum of Ireland](http://www.museum.ie/en/homepage.aspx) (free!) is a must for anyone interested in Irish History from about 500 to 5000 years ago. Beyond that, there's loads else to do, but your specific interests will govern which to do.

If the weather was good and you were all a bit younger, I'd suggest taking the airport bus then doing an organised or self-guided walking tour, probably including a museum/gallery or two. With lots of walking being a potential issue, paying a bit extra for the bus seems worth it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no DART that serves the airport (at least there wasn't 2 years ago). You'll have to take a bus or a taxi to get to Dublin center.

As to where to take your *oldies*, it is kind of hard to suggest without knowing them or what sort of activities they like to do. Usually old people tend to be more religious, so perhaps, showing them the St Patricks Cathedral (and St Patricks Park on the side) might be a good idea. Dublin Castle is not far from the Cathedral (within walking range if they do not have any health condition that impairs them from walking) and is also a nice place to see. Lots of history and nice old buildings.

Comment: Thanks for a nice suggestion, gmauch. Accepting, because there's no alternative answer for this moment. However, taking into account, that my _oldies_ are by far more lazy than religious, I think that spending lazy half-day anywhere on the cost sounds as a better option. I know, that there isn't direct connection from the airport to DART, but I recall, that there isn't much distance between airport and the Portmanock's DART station. Getting there by bus shouldn't be to hard. And, aside DART station, Portmanock itself is beautiful coast city, if I'm not mistaken.